# Many duplicate errors when trying to recompile a Visual Studio 2019 C# project

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I've spent the last 4 hours trying to fix this problem, but it seems to me to be a Visual Studio bug.

I've developed for a customer a standalone C# Windows app in 2019, using WPF and .NET Framework 4.5.

Now I've to do a small change, and so reopen the project and try to compile in Visual Studio.

Unfortunately I get a lot of errors like the following:

[image]

It says every element in my WPF interface is duplicated? How is it possible?

I've read it could be a bug, so I've tried some workaround without success.

I've tried to update to the latest version of the .NET SDK.

I've tried to use this workaround:

```
<Target Name="RemoveDuplicateAnalyzers" BeforeTargets="CoreCompile">
    <!-- Work around https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/6792 -->

    <ItemGroup>
        <FilteredAnalyzer Include="@(Analyzer->Distinct())" />
        <Analyzer Remove="@(Analyzer)" />
        <Analyzer Include="@(FilteredAnalyzer)" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

The errors remain. Do you have an idea how to solve this?

Thank you in advance.
Pietro

Comment: Have you tried to Clean the project and delete the obj and bin folders?

Comment: The Error List view (especially when Build + Intellisense is activated) does often not tell you the first error you should look at. I recommend you have a look a the Output window, which error occurs there at first.

Comment: Thank you mate, ths solve the issue.
It was something in the obj folder.
I've deleted the whole folder, and it worked.

Comment: @DocBrown Seriously, the very first thing I do when installing Visual Studio on a new project is to disable the setting that brings up the Error window every time.  The second thing I do is install an extension that adds coloring to the output window called "VSColorOutput64" so that errors and warnings appear in different  colors